# Is there a system variable to access the last subroutine return value in Perl?

Tags: perl

Perl has a system variables for generically accessing variables within a given context, for example, using `$1` to after a regular expression to access the first grouped item or `$_` in a loop to access the current value.

I was curious if there is a similar system variable for returned values from subroutines.

ex.

```
my $var = (format($num)) ? $_ : 'N/A';
```

where `$_` would be the system variable to access the result of `format($num)` if it is defined.

Comment: I see where you want to go with that... but what you can do is `my $var = format($num) || ’N/A’;`

Comment: You're misunderstanding the nature of Perl built-in variables. They aren't some sort of introspection facility—they have a clearly-defined purpose. `$1`, `$2` etc. store the captured substrings from each successful regex pattern match. That is their only purpose, and while it is possible to persuade a pattern match to store the captures elsewhere *as well*, the primary location is these built-in numbered variables. Likéwise, `$_` doesn't store the current value of a `for`loop control variable unless you have written your code that way. It is the *default* variable if you provide no other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, there is not.**

However, you can rewrite your example to use either the [*or* `||`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or) or the [*defined-or* `//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator.

```
my $foo = frobnicate() || 'N/A'; # only true values, so no 0, q{} or undef
my $bar = frobnicate() // 'N/A'; # no undef
```

Of course this will not keep the value around for a while to use it further down in the code.

This will also only work if the return value of the sub is only one value. If there is a list returned, it will use the right-most value from the list.

```
sub frobnicate { qw/a b 0/ }
my $var = frobnicate() || 'N/A';
say $var;
```

The above will print `N/A`.

```
sub frobnicate { qw/a b c/ }
my $var = frobnicate() || 'N/A';
say $var;
```

While this will print `c`.

---

Don't try to be short for the sake of having short code. Most of the time, what you want is *easy to read* code instead.

---

Note that [`format` is a keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html). Don't use it as a subroutine identifier.

Comment: I understand the need for easy to read code.  In this case, I am building an object which has several numeric properties.  I am merely converting floats into integers with comma separations, so in this case, I see it as being neater than a long chain of if condition assignment blocks.

Comment: @DanielFoust I'm curious to see the code. If you'd like some feedback, please post it to [codereview.se] and ping me with a link here.